# How best to manage an integer column used to denote priority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to manage an ActiveRecord model via its `priority:integer` column. I would like to manage the rows with `after_update` and `after_create` hooks to keep their order neat and clean.

I have two needs:

1. Take a current list of items and update their priority attribute to follow strict order. 
   Example: a list of three items with said priority column.

   ```
   [a.priority = 4, b.priority = 66, c.priority = 92]
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   [a.priority = 1, b.priority = 2, c.priority = 3]
   ```
2. Update all rows' priority to reflect the addition of a new row in the middel of the list.

   ```
   [a.priority = 1, b.priority = 2, c.priority = 3, d.priority = 4]
   ```

   with an addition of `e.priority = 2` create a new list of

   ```
   [a.priority = 1, e.priority = 2, b.priority = 3, c.priority = 4, d.priority = 5]
   ```

**github repo: https://github.com/digitalcake/priority_manager**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for; obviously number 1 is trivial, and number two seems relatively straight-forward. Where are you having issues?

Comment: My problem is I'm not really sure were to start. If its not too trivial could you show what you would do with what I have outlined? 

I get this maybe different to do in the context of an array vs working at the db level so what ever works best for you.

Comment: For the first one you'd set the priority to the index+1. Once you've done that you know where to insert new items; you could simply create a new array with the pre-new-item items, append the new item, then append the rest after incrementing their indices.

Comment: `a`, `b`, `c`, ... represent separate rows (i.e. model instances) right? And you want to be able to insert `e` at a specific position in the list and have the other `priority` values updated, right?

Comment: mu is too short your are correct

Comment: acts_as_list does a lot of this IIRC. getting everything to stay consistent in the presence of concurrent inserts/updates is a lot trickier

Comment: I'd probably write a trigger inside the database to sort things out. But triggers upset the Rails people because they conflict with their ideology. The solutions would boil down to some variation of Alex's below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case, you could do something like

```
Model.order("priority ASC").each_with_index {|m,i| 
  m.update_attribute(:priority, i+1) }
```

And the second one

```
Model.where("priority >= ?", new_priority).each {|m| 
  m.update_attribute(:priority, m + 1) }
```

That said, if you are only interested in the ordering and not the absolute position on the list it would be more efficient if instead of using integers to store your priorities, you used floats. Insert a row by assigning a it value between the priorities of the objects you want it to be in between. IE to insert *a* between *b* and *c* with respective priorities *pb* and *pc* assign it a priority of *pa* = (*pc* + *pb*) / 2

This way the overall ordering remains intact, but you dont need to touch and resave every object with a higher priority every time you insert a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I just handled the exact same scenario in one of the apps I am building.
The solution in the accepted answer did not work as it will recursively use callbacks to call the object you are trying to update (inside update_attributes). Also we need to skip the id for self object inside the query.

Here is how I am doing it finally, and it does seem to work for all cases.

```
after_commit :order_priorities, :if => :persisted?
after_destroy :handle_priorities_when_destroyed

def order_priorities
    correct_priority = MyModel.where('id != ? AND priority < ?',id,priority).count + 1
    MyModel.where.not(id:id).order(:priority).each_with_index {|x,i|
        if x.priority < priority
            x.update_column(:priority, i+1) 
        else
            x.update_column(:priority, i+2)
        end
    }
    self.update_column(:priority,correct_priority) 
end

def handle_priorities_when_destroyed
    MyModel.where.not(id:id).order(:priority).each_with_index {|x,i|
            x.update_column(:priority, i+1)
    }
end
```

Here I am using after_commit callback, so that I will be able to set correct_priority for self that I define in my method. Other callbacks will not work as the value will be overwritten during commit.

Using update_column, so that callbacks are skipped when I do not want them.

Logic is self explanatory.